# Complete replace of a cel in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
       <td class="1">cell 1</td>
       <td class="2">cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="3">cell 3</td>
       <!-- from here -->
       <td class="4">cell 4</td>
       <!-- to here -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I need is to replace the all the code from cell 4 in JavaScript, I mean replace

```
<td class="4">cell 4</td>
```

with

```
<td id="8" class="3" title="important">cell 4</td>
```

I tried this:

```
var cell = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[1].cells;
cell[1] = newCode;
```

Comment: _"Is it possible?"_ Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: yes, are you stuck at solving it? please show us what you tried?

Comment: so remove the element and append a new td.

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use JQuery for that. something like this: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Hope it helps

EDIT:

In your example you could use something like this:

```
$( ".4" ).replaceWith( "<td id="8" class="3" tittle="important">cell 4</td>" );
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17178310)

Comment: @EJoshuaS Thank you for your feedback. I cleared it up

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var h1 = document.getElementsByClassName("4")[0];
    var atttittle = document.createAttribute("tittle");
    atttittle.value = "important";
    h1.setAttributeNode(atttittle);
    var attid = document.createAttribute("id");
    attid.value = "8";
    h1.setAttributeNode(attid);
    var attclass = document.createAttribute("class");
    attclass.value = "3";
    h1.setAttributeNode(attclass);
    var element=document.getElementById("8");
        alert(element.outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
       <td class="1">cell 1</td>
       <td class="2">cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="3">cell 3</td>
       <td class="4">cell 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click here replace </button>
</body>
</html>
```

sorry for previous answer.I changed to JavaScript

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag on the question

Comment: @j08691,sorry for previous answer.I have changed to JavaScript,How check, I hope  this is useful